# Wix installer "A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run."

Tags: wix

Wix 3.10, Visual Studio 2013, Web app deployment, .net.

After installation, it seems like all the files are all right. They are in the right place, the web application seems to be working all right.

However when the installer finished installing, I have one of these errors saying

> Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: .... Product
>   Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: ...
>   Installation success or error status: 1603.
>
> Product: Vendor Master Database -- Error 1723. There is a problem with
>   this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to
>   complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package
>   vendor.

How can I trace it down what is his problem? There are 10-15 dll-s involved in the Web Application is one of those the issue? (one of my own dll-s) Or this is more like a "system" dll from the Operating System or from Wix?

How can I debug this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still newbie, but I had the same issue as you.
It was my CustomAction.

To debug your code, you can use the command line :

```
msiexec.exe /i c:\PathToYourMsi\YourMsi.msi /L*vx c:\PathToYourLog.txt
```

You can find more information:

http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm
https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/kb/314881

Comment: ok thanks, I didn't know this. Looks like I have a 1154 error

Comment: Did you fix your issue? I created a .bat with this command line - I'm able to run my MSI with logs by double click on the bat.... much easier and much faster !

Comment: I found another link that can be useful for you (explain how to log the installer with different ways) : http://www.christiano.ch/wordpress/windows-installer-msi-kb/msi-understanding-the-windows-installer-logs/

Answer (score 3):

Look inside your Binary element. If you have included `CustomAction.dll` instead of `CustomAction.CA.dll` change it. It should be `CustomAction.CA.dll`, because it is a wrapper around your dll file which has **C#** as well as **WiX** information.

That's what caused this error in my case.

Comment: In my case it's not generating CustomAction.CA.dll in bin folder. it has only CustomAction.dll, how to fix it?